# Not starting NFS kernel daemon: no support in current kernel

Tags: nfs

I tried to follow these instructions for setting up NFS server on 12.04:

```
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo
```

`/etc/default/portmap` doesn't exist so I skipped that part.

After editing `/etc/exports` I tried to restart/start the NFS service but I get the following error which I don't understand, everything was installed from apt-get:

```
davidparks21@hadoop-fsimage-bkup1:~$ sudo service nfs-kernel-server start
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0-27-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
 * Not starting NFS kernel daemon: no support in current kernel.
```

---

I should **strongly note** that this is a 12.04 LXC container that's running in a 12.10 host!

Update: Tested in a 12.10 LXC container and I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within an LXC container you cannot run NFS because it's kernel based (e.g. it will only run on the host). UNFS and other user-space NFS servers are an option.